# Pygame: Test if entity collides with another of itself?

Tags: pygame

So I am working on a tiny little 2d voxxel game in Pygame, and I want the blocks that you place to be gravity affected, but in order to do this.. I need an entity to be able to collide "with itself" (as in another one of itself). Here is the collision code:

```
for block in blocklist:
    if block.rect.colliderect(block.rect):
        exit()
```

exit() is just to verify when the event returns positive, but unfortunately, whenever I create one block... it detects the collision with itself and exits.

What can I do to get around this?

Thanks!
-Sam

Comment: You're testing to see if the object collides with itself - of course it will return true.

Comment: Well how can I do that otherwise!?

Comment: Are you using sprite groups?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example just checks the first block in your list against itself - it's always going to collide.

You want to test each block in the list, against every other block in the list:

```
for block in blocklist:
    if any(block.rect.colliderect(x.rect) for x in blocklist if x is not block):
        exit()
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thank you so much! ^.^